# Where on my server is the PHP version that serves web pages?

Tags: php, apache, server, shared-hosting, php-5.6

I'm on a shared server. When I save a script with `phpinfo()` and open it in the browser, the script tells me "PHP Version 5.6.18":

[image]

When I visit my server through SSH and look in `/usr/local/bin`, `ls` shows me PHP versions from 4 to 5.5, but no version 5.6:

[image]

When I search for PHP with `which php`, I get the following (with results from `... -v` in parentheses):

```
/usr/bin/php (4.4.9)
/usr/bin/php4.4
/usr/bin/php5.2
/usr/bin/php5.4
/usr/bin/php5.5
/usr/bin/php5.4-cli
/usr/bin/php5.5-cli
/usr/bin/php4.4-cli
/usr/bin/php5.2-cli
/usr/lib/php (directory, contains extensions)
/usr/lib/php4.4
/usr/lib/php5.4
/usr/lib/php5.5
/usr/lib/php5.2
/usr/local/bin/php (4.4.9)
/usr/local/bin/php5.4
/usr/local/bin/php5.5
/usr/local/bin/php4.4
/usr/local/bin/php5.2
/usr/local/lib/php.ini-nourl
/usr/include/php4.4
/usr/include/php5.4
/usr/include/php5.5
/usr/include/php5.2
/usr/local/php (4.4.9)
/usr/share/php (directory, contains: libzend-framework-php  wp-cli)
```

So where is PHP 5.6?

I want to run a script through a cronjob using the same PHP or a similar version as the one serving web pages, e.g.

```
0 * * * *  /usr/local/bin/php5.6 -f/path/to/script.php
```

but I don't know where PHP 5.6 lives.

**How can I find PHP 5.6 on my server?**

I'm on a shared Linux server running Apache. I called my hosting provider but the weekend staff has no idea and asked me to call on Monday. Can you help me before then?

Comment: It's totally possible that your apache/nginx runs a different PHP version. You can get the cli version (path) by `$ which php`.

Comment: What's the actual question here? If you want to know which executable your apache uses you gotta look in the configs.

Comment: Maybe you ain't got the permissions to access/see the 5.6 executable. You should get in contact w/ your host.

Comment: Try a `locate bin/php` or `locate bin/php5` to do some searching - the binary may not be in the folder you're looking at. I expect it would be listed in your web-based `phpinfo()` as well.

Comment: Since this host has PHP 4 installed, I would move to another server, or another host, pretty quickly. PHP 4 is well out of date, and I would consider it a security risk presently, even if they have hardened it with patches outside of the PHP project. I can't think of any reason for running this version these days.

Comment: @what: you could make that sort of case for 5.2, just about, but not PHP 4. It went out of support on 7 August 2008; "it's a hobby" or "I'm busy" is not a good basis for keeping unmaintained and potentially insecure code on a server.

Comment: @what: I'm not sure your analogy holds true. Removing PHP 4 won't take a PHP gun away from customers: it just takes a rusty blunderbuss away from people who don't know that old guns are dangerous. Customers are free to do something stupid with PHP 5 or 7 deliberately if they wish, but the safety catch is better on both.

Comment: You have a good administrator. I saw already 4 years old PHP version running....

Comment: @AlBundy A provider will make more money if they support hobbyists who do not have the knowledge or time to update their code regularly. If I had to adapt my code to a new PHP version every year, I would not make websites. I simply don't have the time. My code has been mostly unchanged since 2009. I don't care about security, because there is nothing sensitive on my site. If hackers exploit my code to send spam or whatever, I don't care. I don't do business on the web, because anonymity and "freedom" are making the web unsafe, not old code.

Answer (score 1):

PHP constant **PHP_BINARY** keeps info of current PHP interpreter:

```
<?php var_dump(PHP_BINARY); ?>
```

It'll return soomething like this: `string(13) "/usr/bin/php5"`.
Then:

```
$ /usr/bin/php5 -v
```

In your specific case probably `php5` is the PHP v5.6.

Comment: Nice, thank you. This returns `string(23) "/usr/lib/cgi-bin/php5.6"`. Now I can see if crond is allowed to use this.

Comment: Oops, but actually `-bash: /usr/lib/cgi-bin/php5.6: No such file or directory`. Hmm, now that is strange ...

Comment: yeah, on shared hosts it is somewhat tricky. Uncheck my answer and wait someone else to answer.

Answer (score 0):

use `/usr/local/bin/php`, since the higher version of php in your server is 5.6 the default php file is the 5.6 version

Comment: `/usr/local/bin/php -v` tells me it is "PHP 4.4.9 (cgi-fcgi)".

Comment: beside this looks weird or the server may got updated manually, Your only options for now is to use the versions you can, If you need php 5.6 for some reason try upload your own php5.6 binary file into a writable directory and execute it. this could work simply, But if you are not the root, You can't make it default.
By the way check :
`/usr/local/bin/php5 -v`

Comment: sorry for too much questions, But i just want to understand your server environment:
dose this file exists, and what version is it `/etc/alternatives/php -v`

Comment: Ha, don't worry. I'm glad for your help, so just ask away. But no, there is no php in `/etc/alternatives`.

Comment: will I had run to this problem before but I just re-installed php, anyway 
I think the only way I can help by uploading this php binary file for php v 5.6.17 from my PC
http://ge.tt/7saXROY2
Good luck, By the way you can check the hash of the file or scan it if you are suspicious